NavigationExtension to replace Tridion Sites 10 logo with other brand logo
I'm currently learning how to create different add-ons and extensions for Tridion Sites 10 and I've been using the documentation and different examples that are provided as learning resources.
There are a lot of examples on how to interact with nagivation items and customize the navigation section of the header but there is no documentation on how to access the logo/brand part of the header to customize the logo or even replace the Link component with a different one.
Is the branding part of the header not accessible in any way on purpose?

We're hearing of customers changing the Experience Space header by manipulating the markup (DOM) directly. So this should be possible, if not directly "supported." I'll ask around if there's an example. Oh and the ability to influence the Experience Space header is a familiar request (even one that I and a few others submitted an idea for in the Classic UI), so it's probably more about focus and priorities than intentionally blocking this kind of customization.


Tridion Sites 10 doesn't support custom interactions with logo component in the main navigation bar.
Any extension point that allows to supply custom React component can be suitable for any DOM alternations or injections.
Suggested approach is not safe in terms of stability and compatibility in the future but works as a workaround before such endpoint will be added.

@Alan, Can you clarify Link replacement problem, what is the goal there?
